# Convolution of r.v.'s

Tags: probability

Suppose a sequence $\{X_{n} \}$ of pairwise independent r.v.'s. If $F_{X_n}$ is the distribution function of $X_n$ then $ F_{X_1 + \ldots + X_{N}} = F_{X_1} \ast F_{X_2 + \ldots + X_{N}}$ (convolution) for some $N>1$ fixed?

Comment: Do the case $N=2$.  Write down the definition of $F_{X_1+X_2}$.  What do you get?

Comment: @GEdgar Bad example, the story begins at $N=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent Bernoulli$(0.5)$ random variables ($1$ with probability $\frac 12$, $0$ with probability $\frac 12$) and set $X_3 = |X_1-X_2|$.

Then $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are pairwise independent Bernoulli$(0.5)$ random variables, but $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ is always even. This is not the same as the iid case.